# SQL getting Percentage

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, percentage

I have the following code to calculate total fatalities and group by the PersonType. Now I want to have a column that calculates the percentage of each fatalities. that is taking the value for each person type and dividing by the total fatalities.

```
Select distinct persontype as PerSsonType, sum(fatalities_in_crash) as  Total_Deaths

  from [CarCrash].[Source_Data_Staging] 
group by PersonType
```

[image]

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ANSI-standard window functions (which are supported by most databases including SQL Server):

```
Select persontype as PerSsonType, sum(fatalities_in_crash) as Total_Deaths,
       sum(fatalities_in_crash) * 1.0 / sum(sum(fatalities_in_crash)) over () as ratio
from [CarCrash].[Source_Data_Staging] 
group by PersonType;
```

Note:  You almost never need `SELECT DISTINCT` with `GROUP BY`.  And the `* 1.0` is because some databases use integer division -- which would produce `0` for all your rows.

Answer (score 1):

You can cross-join this query with a query that select the sum of deaths without grouping:

```
SELECT   persontype, 
         SUM(fatalities_in_crash) AS Total_Deaths,
         SUM(fatalities_in_crash) / all_deaths AS percentage
FROM     [CarCrash].[Source_Data_Staging] 
JOIN     (SELECT SUM(fatalities_in_crash) AS all_deaths
          FROM   [CarCrash].[Source_Data_Staging]) t
GROUP BY persontype
```